# How to save an image from google colaboratory without cutting it in python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using google colaboratory and trying to save some plots in pdf format for further use. But some text of the labels from the plots have been totally or partially cut while rendering the images in pdf or png format. Using Jupyter notebook gives the same result. Is there any solution to this?

```
from google.colab import files
plt.savefig("Fid.pdf")
files.download("Fid.pdf")
```

There is no error message shown.[Half of the x label text of this plot has been cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjEto.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using this code.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.savefig("Fid.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
files.download("Fid.pdf")
```

This should work. If it works do not forget to click the upvote button and mark this answer as accepted please.